# c# накладывание фильтров на изображение

Tags: c#, изображения, graphics, filter

Стоит задача накладывать на изображение различные фильтры. Т.е. добавить в картинку помехи, рябь, сделать его черно-белым, изменение яркости и т.д.
Наверняка для таких операций существует готовая библиотека, но поиск выдает только различные учебники по реализации подобных фильтров

По одному из гайдов написал изменение яркости... но зачем делать то, что уже готово и оптимизировано

```
public static Image ChangeBrightness(Bitmap image, float brightness) {
    ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
    int width = image.Width;
    int height = image.Height;

    float[][] colorMatrixElements = {
            new float[] {brightness, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, brightness, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, brightness, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    };

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(colorMatrixElements);

    imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(
        colorMatrix,
        ColorMatrixFlag.Default,
        ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0, width,
        height,
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
        imageAttributes);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: [AForge.Imaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AForge.Imaging/)

Comment: Так а вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov какие готовые библиотеки существуют для такой задачи

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно подобные вещи уже реализованы.

Могу посоветовать OpenCV. В ней реализованы практически все операции, которые можно делать с изображениями. В оригинале либа написана на C++, но если open source реализация на C# - [openCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp).

Функционал огромен, но конкретно по вашему вопросу можно посмотреть в [вот этот семпле](https://github.com/VahidN/OpenCVSharp-Samples/blob/master/OpenCVSharpSample10/Program.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Я изменяю яркость так, где число 128 это мат. ожидание:

```
double k = 20.0;
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"E:/bmw.jpg");
bool[,] array = new bool[img.Height, img.Width];
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
Color[,] colorM = new Color[img.Height, img.Width];
for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
    {
        int r = img.GetPixel(j, i).R;
        int g = img.GetPixel(j, i).G;
        int b = img.GetPixel(j, i).B;
        r = (int)(r + k * 128 / 100);
        g = (int)(g + k * 128 / 100);
        b = (int)(b + k * 128 / 100);
        if (r > 255)
            r = 255;
        if (g > 255)
            g = 255;
        if (b > 255)
            b = 255;
        var color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        bm.SetPixel(j, i, color);
        //Console.WriteLine(img.GetPixel(j, i));
    }
}
bm.Save("E://bmw2.jpg");
```